# Adobe Edge Animation on Digital Signage Media?

Tags: adobe-edge

One of my client has asked me to create an Animation for his Digital Signage Media. He is running a fast food restaurant and want to run the animation. So that the user can interact with the menu and other stuff.

My Question is that " Adobe Edge created animations will run on Digital Signage Player ?"

Comment: What Happen to your project ? did it go with Adobe Edge ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of player. Adobe Edge just outputs an HTML(5) file along with the scripts required to run your animation- all in a single folder.